# Multiple functions in a single IF statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, multipleoutputs

So what I wanna do is when a user pushes the submit button, a php query is run. In that php query if an "If statement" condition is fulfilled, I want to execute an operation (which in my case is a page redirection) and return false.

[EDIT] The whole query code is something like this:

```
add_filter( ‘mycred_add’, ‘mycred_pro_restrict_negative_balances’, 1, 3 );
function mycred_pro_restrict_negative_balances( $reply, $request, $mycred ) {

  if ( $reply === false || $request[‘amount’] > 0 ) return $reply;

  extract( $request );

  // Users current balance
  $current_balance = $mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $type );

  // If balance is zero – decline OR If we are deducting points, make sure the amount will not take us below zero
  if (( $current_balance <= 0 )||(($current_balance – abs( $amount )) < 0 )) {
    $redirect_to_page = 22;
    return false;
  }

  return $reply;

}
```

I wanna know if the query will work?? And if there's something wrong with it, please do mention the correction. Thanks in advance for helping / trying to help me.

Comment: Where is the return value used if the page is simply being redirected?

Comment: Why not test it out yourself instead? It's simple code and won't take you long to debug / find out.

Comment: The return value is used, to return the balance deduction request. Ya I errored to having it placed after the redirect.

Comment: @Epodax I'm a site manager not the admin and the admin has requested me to complete this problem and provide him with the solution in about a day from now.

Answer (score 1):

In your calling function, test for a FALSE return value. If it's false, then call your redirection after processing any other actions you need to do upon this function returning FALSE.

Comment: Ya that's exactly what I need to learn, how exactly do I test for a FALSE.

Comment: Can it be something like /* if (return false == true) { $redirect_to_page = 10;}

Comment: @JoeWilkinson If your function that this code is in is called say `testForX()`, you would do:

`if(testForX() == FALSE) { $redirect_to_page = 10; }` or simply using the `!` (not operator) like `if(!testForX()) { $redirect_to_page = 10; }`

Comment: Thanks man I'll try this and let u know ASAP. BTW I've updated the whole query above. Could you please see to that once and confirm with the answer you provided. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it before, but there is another issue in that the variable that you're setting (`$redirect_to_page`) isn't actually being used anywhere. When you return `false`, that's the only thing that's returned. The value of that variable is never used, unless it's a global.

Answer (score 0):

You probably nead something like that:

```
if ( $current_balance <= 0 ) {
 /* Redirection */
 header("Location: http://www.example.com/page10.php"); 
 exit();
}
```

Sending header 'Location' will tell browser to go to specified URL. That's the simplest way of redirection. You don't have to return false.